# How to sort pandas dataframe from list category?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

so I have this data set below that I want to sort base on mylist from column 'name' as well as acsending by 'A'  and descending by 'B'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6]) , ('name', ['x','x','x'])])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('B', [5, 6, 7]), ('A', [8, 9, 10]) , ('name', ['y','y','y'])])
    df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('C', [5, 6, 7]), ('D', [8, 9, 10]), ('A',[1,2,3]), ('B',[4,5,7] ), ('name', ['z','z','z'])])
    df_list = [df1,df2,df3[['A','B','name']]]
    df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

so my list is

```
  mylist = ['z','x','y']
```

I want the dataset to start with  sort by my list , then sort asc column A then desc column B

is there a way to do this in python ?

[image]

======== Edit ==========
I want my final result to be something like

[image]

Comment: Sorry are you looking for `df.sort(['A','B','name'], ascending=[True, False,True])`?

Comment: @EdChum for name I am not trying to ascending it , I want it to custom z,x,y   => not z,y,x

Comment: So is `df.sort(['A','B'], ascending=[True, False])` what you're after then?

Comment: correct for that part. but I couldn't figure it out how to do name as well as those 2 at the same time, if that makes sense

Comment: Sorry no it doesn't, is your output df actually what you're after because that is whay I get after the `concat` without any sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, a way to sort by a custom order is to create a dict that defines how 'name' column should be order, call `map` to add a new column that defines this new order, then call [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort) and pass in the new column and the others, plus the param `ascending` where you selectively decide whether each column is sorted ascending or not, and then finally drop that column:

```
In [20]:

name_sort = {'z':0,'x':1,'y':2}
df['name_sort'] = df.name.map(name_sort)
df
Out[20]:
    A  B name  name_sort
0   1  4    x          1
1   2  5    x          1
2   3  6    x          1
3   8  5    y          2
4   9  6    y          2
5  10  7    y          2
6   1  4    z          0
7   2  5    z          0
8   3  7    z          0
In [23]:

df = df.sort(['name_sort','A','B'], ascending=[1,1,0])
df
Out[23]:
    A  B name  name_sort
6   1  4    z          0
7   2  5    z          0
8   3  7    z          0
0   1  4    x          1
1   2  5    x          1
2   3  6    x          1
3   8  5    y          2
4   9  6    y          2
5  10  7    y          2
In [25]:

df = df.drop('name_sort', axis=1)
df
Out[25]:
    A  B name
6   1  4    z
7   2  5    z
8   3  7    z
0   1  4    x
1   2  5    x
2   3  6    x
3   8  5    y
4   9  6    y
5  10  7    y
```

Comment: just note that sort is deprecated, sort_values should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Hi We can do the above issue by using the following:

```
t = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['z','x','y'], ordered=True)
df['sort'] = pd.Series(df.name, dtype=t)
df.sort_values(by=['sort','A','B'], inplace=True)
```