# sorting in pandas dataframe by particular category in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to sort the dataframe by Categories.That is I have to select the column ['Category'] and again sort it .

The categories are as follows:

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: `df=df.sort_values('Category')`?

Comment: You can find you solution from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29347595/16258342)